# Memory leak detection

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers

**Do anyone know of a general algorithm to detect memory leak?**

Comment: in what language? or to be less specific, under what memory management paradigm? From your tagging I would guess C?

Comment: And in what context?  Are you trying to, for example, write a tool that looks for memory leaks in running code?  Or are you assuming that you have hooks into the dynamic memory management routines so that your memory profiler can intercept memory allocation requests?

Comment: The tool is called #define malloc.  You allocate your own block header and keep it on a linked list.  See Writing Solid Code, the book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memory Leak Analysis by Contradiction

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rugina/papers/sas06.pdf

And less relevantly...

Apple dev docs have an article on the topic also (specific)...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html

and on tracking memory usage generally (also specific)...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001882-CJBJFIDD

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to have a counter for each kind of object you have in your application. When allocating an object increase the counter, when dellocating decrease it. When the application terminates, check that all counters are zero.

Comment: Hmm, now you also have to debug the reference counting bugs.  Double the job.

Comment: This is much harder to do in C, as opposed to C++.

Comment: Hans: I'm not talking about reference counting, only a simple pair of alloc and dealloc functions, for each type used, wrapping malloc and free. In my opinion, all well-designed application should have these anyway.

Comment: You can probably get by without object specific counters, just a single one should suffice to ensure you have balanced malloc/calloc() to free() calls.

Answer (score 1):

While not an algorithm, there are a plethora of 3rd party tools that will help analyze your code for memory leaks as well. Depending on the size of your project, it might not be reasonable to manually track all allocations yourself.

I personally like to use valgrind if i am in a *nix environment.

alternative, let your program run for a long time and watch the memory allocation the process uses from top or task manager. If it's leaking, it will consistently go up. If not, it should inflate to it's maximum value then hold stay, or fluctuate between this and a lower value.

Unfortunately growth does not necessarily equal a leak, could just be your program needs A LOT of memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows you need deleaker. If you use *nix try valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the way to detect memory leak in the preprocessor directives of the code include these statements

```
 # define _CRTDbg_Map_Alloc

 # include<stdlib.h>

 # include<crtdbg.h>
```

and in the main function use this function to dump the memory leaks.

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```